# Maximal ideals corresponding to points on curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was reading up on algebraic geometry and it was stated that if $C$ is a curve in the affine $n$-space $\mathbb{A}^n$? then all prime ideals of $k[C]$, the set of all regular functions on $C$, are maximal ideals corresponding to points in $C$. I know that if $C$ is a curve, then all prime ideals in $k[C]$ are maximal ideals since $k[C]$ is a UFD. I also know that all maximal ideals in $k[\mathbb{A}^n]=k[x_1,\cdots x_n]$ corresponds to points in $k$. However I am unable to see how this is the case for a curve $C$. I can see roughly how this passes on to the case of curves. But how does one show this in a rigorous manner? Any help/hints given would be greatly appreciated! Here we assume $k$ is an algebraically closed field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is true only for an algebraically closed field. The reason for the assertion is that $k[C] $ is a quotient of some $k[\mathbf A^n]$, hence its spectrum corresponds to the Zariski-closed set $V(I)$ in $k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$, where $I$ is the ideal of polynomials which vanish on $C$ .

In this correspondence, maximal ideals correspond to maximal ideals (by the $3^{\textit{rd}}$ *isomorphism theorem*).

Comment: Hi Bernard! Thank you for your reply. I did thought of the isomorphism theorem. However there is still one thing that is not clear to me. I know that one has $k[X_1,\cdots, X_n]/I(C)$ is isomorphic to $k[C]$. Given this isomorphism, how do I determine the maximal ideals of $k[C]$? More explicitly, how does the maximal ideals of $k[X_1,\cdots, X_n]/I(C)$ look like?

Comment: They're simply $\mathfrak m/I(C)$  for all maximal ideals $\mathfrak m\supset I(C)$. Over an algebraically closed field, the Nullstellensatz  says it is the same as the points $(\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n)$ which satisfy the equations defining the curve.